# Show that $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}\Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}=:e$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I write out the left term expression and get 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\bigg(\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^k
$$
If I could Show that the k-th term of both sequences is equal I would be done.
 
I.e what I want to show is

$$\binom{n}{k}\bigg(\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^k=\frac{n\cdot\ldots\big((n-k)+1\big)}{k!}\bigg(\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^k\overset{!}{=}\frac{1}{k!}$$

The approach must be wrong, because the above statement would be equivalent to say that

$$\frac{n\cdot\ldots\big(n-(k-1)\big)}{n^k}=1$$

which is not true.

How can I solve the Problem? I also want to ask if I could Show the left side of the implication in the title, why is the Right side true?

Comment: You might cannot prove that $(1+1/n)^n = \sum_0^n 1/k!$ because such equation cannot hold, if I have remembered correctly.

Comment: It's not true : $(1+\frac{1}{2})^2=\frac{9}{4}$ while $1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}=2,5$.

Comment: Since $p\implies q$ is true when $p$ is false, you may want to change the title of this post if what you really want to show is $q$, namely the identity about $e$.

Answer (score 0):

The condition $a_n=b_n$ for all $n$ is *sufficient* but not *necessary* for 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n.
$$

Note that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}=:e\tag{1}
$$
But 
$
(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}
$
is not even true for $n=2$.

Here is a sketch for one way to show (1).

Let
$$
s_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!},\quad t_n=(1+\frac{1}{n})^n.
$$

**Step 1.** Use the binomial theorem to show that $t_n\le s_n$. (Exercise!) It then follows that
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}t_n\le e.\tag{2}
$$

**Step 2.** If $n\ge m$, (applying the binomial theorem again)
$$
t_n\ge 1+1+\frac{1}{2!}(1-\frac{1}{n})+\cdots+\frac{1}{m!}(1-\frac1n)\cdots(1-\frac{m-1}{n}).
$$
It follows that for any fixed $m$, 
$$
s_m\le\liminf_{n\to\infty} t_n.
$$
Letting $m\to\infty$, one gets
$$
e\le\liminf_{n\to\infty} t_n.\tag{3}
$$
You get the desired result by combining (2) and (3).